# NPM modules get required from /Users/node_modules/ instead of the project directory

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, react-native

My react-native project has been working well until I upgraded react-native from 0.17 to 0.18 and then 0.19.

Ever since the upgrade any module (e.g. app-module-path) that I:

1. successfully install using npm - `npm install --save app-module-path`
2. add `require('app-module-path').addPath(__dirname);` in my code

give the following error when running the simulator:

`Unable to resolve module from /Users/MyUserName/myfolder/projectname/node_modules/app-module-path/lib/index.js: Invalid directory /Users/node_modules/module`

It seems it is looking for the module in the wrong path. I tried to clear all the caches, uninstall an reinstall react-native, rebooted my machine after that and even started a clean project from scratch and the problem persists.

I have already tried all the solutions posted on the official issue without any luck:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

npm: 3.3.12
React-Native: 0.19
OSX: 10.11.2
watchman: stable 4.1.0 (bottled), HEAD

I am looking for any type of solution that fixes my environment without loosing my code and all the integrations I have made in the XCode and Android projects to add some of the modules.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I've not ever needed to add `.addPath(__dirname);` to the end of my require statements. Could that be the problem? Have you tried removing it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue... Tried everything that I could find, including downgrading to NPM 2, deleting and reinstalling my node_modules folder, etc... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Node js have group of possible folders that can contain modules. When you install one module sometimes module can be dependent to other modules. You have to install this dependancies manual. For example if the error is like  /Users/node_modules/module you have to install "npm install -S module". It is showing error as missing path in /Users/node_modules because this is the last element of array full with possible paths that can contain modules  (for MAC).

Full list of paths by OS : https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-paths

Answer (score -1):

It seems many are having this issue with no solution:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

I cannot install and use any additional npm packages as a module.

The module path is correct. I cut and paste the path displayed in xcode into a terminal to test path was valid and correct.

Using:

- OS X 10.11.3
- npm 3.3.12
- node v5.5.0
- react-native-cli: 0.1.10
- react-native: 0.21.0
- xcode 7.2.1

No work-arounds helped including:

- npm3
- rm -rf node_modules
- npm start from ./node_modules/react-native.
- watchman watch-del-all
- rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*
- npm cache clean && npm
- install Creating a new project from scratch
- Modifying **react-native/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/index.js:98**

  -shouldThrowOnUnresolvedErrors: (, platform) => platform === 'ios',
  +shouldThrowOnUnresolvedErrors: (, platform) => { return false; },

How does anyone get any work done in react-native without using additional npm packages?